# How to split a dataframe and attach the splitted part in new column?

Tags: r

I want to split a dataframe by changing values in the first column and afterward attach the split part in a new column. An example is given below. However, I end up with a list that I can't process back to a handy dataframe.

the desired output should look like `df_goal`, which is not yet properly formatted.

```
#data

x <-c(1,2,3)
y <-c(20200101,20200101,20200101)
z <-c(4.5,5,7)
x_name <- "ID"
y_name <- "Date"
z_name <- "value"   

df <-data.frame(x,y,z)
names(df) <- c(x_name,y_name,z_name)

#processing

df$date <-format(as.Date(as.character(df$date), format="%Y%m%d"))
df01 <- split(df, f = df$ID)

#goal
a <-c(1)
b <-c(20200101)
c <-c(4.5)
d <-c(2)
e <-c(20200101)
f <-c(5)
g <-c(3)
h <-c(20200101)
i <-c(7)

df_goal <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
```

Comment: Does `data.frame(t(unlist(df01)))` doesn't solve your purpose? Here you need to rename the columns which are munged.

Comment: What happens when you have ID=1 has two rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` and `cbind` to `cbind` each row of a `data.frame` in one row and *keep the type* of the columns.

```
Reduce(function(x,y) cbind(x, df[y,]), 2:nrow(df), df[1,])
#  ID     Date value ID     Date value ID     Date value
#1  1 20200101   4.5  2 20200101     5  3 20200101     7
#Equivalent for the sample dataset: cbind(cbind(df[1,], df[2,]), df[3,])
```

or `do.call` with `split`:

```
do.call(cbind, split(df, 1:nrow(df)))
#  1.ID   1.Date 1.value 2.ID   2.Date 2.value 3.ID   3.Date 3.value
#1    1 20200101     4.5    2 20200101       5    3 20200101       7
#Equivalent for the sample dataset: cbind(df[1,], df[2,], df[3,])
```

In case you have *several rows per ID* you can try:

```
x <- split(df, df$ID)
y <- max(unlist(lapply(x, nrow)))
do.call(cbind, lapply(x, function(i) i[1:y,]))
```

Comment: @GKi, thanks, that worked pretty well.

as zx8754 mentioned above, i was wondering how your solution (do.call(cbind, split(df, 1:nrow(df)))) would look like in case there are several rows per ID. Cuz right now your solution would transpose row by row as there is just one row per ID

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution for your example :

```
new_df = data.frame(list(df[1,],df[2,],df[3,]))
```

And if you want to generalize that on a bigger data.frame :

```
new_list = list()
for ( i in 1:dim(df)[1] ){
    new_list[[i]] = df[i,]
}
new_df = data.frame(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
setNames(Reduce(c, asplit(df, 1)), letters[1:Reduce(`*`, dim(df))])

     a          b          c          d          e          f          g          h          i 
   1.0 20200101.0        4.5        2.0 20200101.0        5.0        3.0 20200101.0        7.0
```

Comment: nice solution! liked it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following code

```
df_goal <- data.frame(t(c(t(df))))
```

such that

```
> df_goal
  X1       X2  X3 X4       X5 X6 X7       X8 X9
1  1 20200101 4.5  2 20200101  5  3 20200101  7
```